# Размер `.apk` и `.aab` файлов в react native

Tags: android, google-play, react-native

Ребят, привет, может кто помочь?

Начал осваивать React Native и обратил внимание что пустой скомпилированный проект занимает 22.5 Мб как в `.apk` так  и в `.aab`. Есть ли возможность уменьшить размер итогового приложения?

В **Play Market** есть приложения по 5-8 Мб и есть предположение что они на React Native написаны.

Спасибо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60630065/how-to-reduce-android-apk-size-in-react-native